# Evaluate a variable inside a variable with thymeleaf

Tags: html, json, thymeleaf

I am receiving bin data as json. The number of bins in each section is different, but for instance it might be:

```
var jsonmsg={"1": "SIXTY", "2": "DISCONNECTED", "3": "TWENTY", "4": "FULL", "5": "TEN"});
```

I already know the number of bins in each section so bins=5 is known

So I am trying to pass the bin number and json values as class
eg: class="bin3 TWENTY"

This is my thymeleaf code

```
<th:block th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, bins, 1)}">
    <div class="grid-item">something else</div>
    <div class="grid-item">something else</div>
    <div class="grid-item"><div th:class="bin+${i}" th:classappend="${jsonmsg.[[${i}]]}"></div></div>
</th:block>
```

class="bin3" works fine, but I can't work out how to request jsonmsg.* correctly. I have also tried without [[]].

I have also tried:

```
th:classappend="${jsonmsg[i]}"
```

I always get the message:

> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression

Comment: What is `JSON.parse`? Is that in Java?

Comment: javascript, as I have stomp.js script getting the data, unless I should be passing the stomp back to java first? That's just a test message though for when there is no stomp running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I think this premise is flawed.

1. I am trying to manipulate a server side process with client side data. The server side rendering is already complete by then so instead I need client side data to be processed client side with javascript, (not thymeleaf). So I will use javascipt classList.add to update classes as required.
2. I should be iterating though the jsonmsg directly, not using integers.

I will leave this flawed question as is, in case anyone else tries to use client side data (like stomp) to manipulate Thymeleaf templates.